# Storing an inline style into jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following img tag,

```
 <img id="image1" src="URL" alt="image1" name="image1" width="137" height="119" border="0" style="position: relative; left: -355px; top: 62px;" >
```

I would like to somehow, onclick, store the following items into seperate variables..

```
  style="position: relative; left: -355px; top: 62px;"

  var left = -355px
  var top = 62px
```

Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that you want to store the image's style into javascript variables when the user clicks the image?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, exactly, just store "style=whatever" into a variable.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) jQuery method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible, have you tried something like this:

```
$('#image1').on('click', function () {
    var style = 'style="' + $(this).attr('style') + '"';
    var left = $(this).css('left');
    var top = $(this).css('top');

    alert(style);
    alert(left);
    alert(top);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZXHX/

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
var imageInfo = {style:null, left:null, top:null};

$('#image1').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  imageInfo.style = $this.attr('style');
  imageInfo.left = $this.css('left');
  imageInfo.top = $this.css('top');
  console.log('Image Clicked: ', imageInfo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the image with jquery, and then access its attributes from there.

```
var img = $("#image1");
var imgStyle = img[0].getAttribute("style");
var imgLeft = img.css("left");
var imgRight = img.css("right");
```

link to jquery's api for css: http://api.jquery.com/css/

In a function:

```
function getDetails(imgId)
{
 var imgDetails = {};
 var img = $("#"+imgId);
 imgDetails.imgStyle = img[0].getAttribute("style");
 imgDetails.imgLeft = img.css("left");
 imgDetails.imgRight = img.css("right");
 return imgDetails;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing an example of this working, and the requested output in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/j7eYf/1/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest your use jquery, it will make the job a lot easier. Try out this example,

```
$("#your trigger").live('click',function ()
{
$("#image1").css({
position: "absolute",
top: 62 + "px",
left: -355 + "px"
});
});
```

Comment: I dont think this answers the question which is essentially, How do I grab these values from the <img> tag.